# When will inactive accounts be deleted?

Tags: support, user-accounts, deleted-accounts

- Will inactive accounts be deleted?
- If so, what happens to questions and answers made by those accounts?
- What are the criteria for deletion?

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog Considering that question doesn't have any answers that would not be helpful.

Comment: @curiousdannii It does have a link to a blog post explaining the policy change.

Comment: Go ahead and write a new answer to this if you think it would help. I'm just disputing that this should be closed as a duplicate of it.

Comment: Since this is a [faq-proposed], I would have updated this question and answer instead of posting a new one.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For years, 1000 [eligible users](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/02/16/when-is-an-account-abandoned/) were culled every day; and for years, far more than 1000 users became eligible on Stack Overflow. By 2017, millions of users were considered inactive but not deleted.

As of May 3, 2017, culling of inactive users is no longer performed; whatever utility this may have once had, we'd likely lost it years before due to the rate-limiting.