# Is there a way to delete an existing account.?

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/can-i-delete-my-account)

Is there a way to delete our existing account from any of the SO account.

Comment: See [Can I delete my account?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5999)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete your existing account from:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/user-deletion.

Also, old inactive accounts are deleted as documented here:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/when-is-an-account-abandoned/

See

1. [Can I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7979/178505)
2. [Why can't I delete my account on my own?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86936/why-cant-i-delete-my-account-on-my-own)
3. [When will inactive accounts be deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48262/when-will-inactive-accounts-be-deleted)