# Does anything happen to users who do nothing?

Tags: discussion, users, spam

I was curious as to whether anything would happen to this user (perhaps not right away, but down the track):

https://stackoverflow.com/users/918511/dnlcllns

They've signed up and done nothing other than take the time to fill in their profile...is this a slightly more intelligent spam method?

I get that they might come to the site to just browse...but doing nothing at all just seems weird to me!

Comment: If they're coming to browse, nothing happens. If they stay away for six months straight, deletion. [Source](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48262/when-will-inactive-accounts-be-deleted)

Comment: Closely related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105218/is-spam-in-the-about-me-field-a-reason-to-worry.  I think the point is not that the account is inactive, but that the "about me" is spammish.

Comment: How *did* you find this account?  As Kevin notes, he had 0 profile views before today

Comment: @AdamRackis, that is funny about the 0 views...I was using this SEDE query http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/2150 and typed in Alcoa (a company I contract for)...

Answer (score 4):

Since he has 0 profile views (or had, until you posted it), I don't think it's very effective spam.  He was last seen less than a week ago, so he probably is coming to browse.  If he doesn't do anything, no one sees his profile (How did you find it anyway?), so why should it be a problem?

Comment: Maybe this a more clever advertising scheme. David Sleeps created that other account and came to "report" it here.

Comment: @Kevin, I'm not concerned about the user (and don't think they are a problem)...I just wanted to know what (if anything) happened to users who do nothing (no questions, no answers, no votes, no comments, no anything)...@Popular Demand answered the question really. +1 all the same.

Comment: On some other sites I have created an associated account just so I can vote. When I see good stuff I want to reward it. Maybe this person was thinking the same way, but then couldn't vote because of not starting at 101 on you very first account?