# How do you delete stackexchange account and a question I submitted?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account)

I want to first delete the question I submitted, then I want to delete my account.

Comment: ...because you're worried about being identified as user192823 in real life?

Comment: May I ask *why* you want to delete your account?

Answer (score 1):

If your question has no answers with positive score, you can delete it by clicking the **delete** link below the question's tags.

If it *has* answers with positive score, you cannot delete it, since that wouldn't be fair to the users who answered.

For instructions on how to delete your account, see [How can I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account).

Accounts with only 1 rep are also auto-deleted after six months of inactivity ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48262/when-will-inactive-accounts-be-deleted)).