# Finding my (beta) Stack Overflow account

Tags: support, user-accounts, beta-phase

I had an account associated with this e-mail account during the Stack Overflow beta. However, when I tired to use it to login it prompted me to sign up again. Did the old accounts get purged at some point? If so, is it possible to get it back?

I did find a thread that indicated inactive account would be removed, I don't think my account would have qualified for removal under those rules.

Any insight would be appreciated, I can't help but feel I have a zombie account out there somewhere!

EDIT: The account may have been created using an e-mail address such as julian-stackoverflow @ splitbits.com; yes I had a phase where I did this :)

Comment: Did you have any rep? Any questions/answers?

Comment: Is any of this the case: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48262/when-will-inactive-accounts-be-deleted ?

Comment: I am not sure about rep, but I definitely had asked and offered answers to several questions. I may have gotten caught in a purge but I think had more activity than that.

Comment: Facing the same problem here, would like to know what answer you get.

Comment: Actually I have more than one account on Stack Exchange so to keep them apart in different sites. Is that against the rules?

Comment: @Buscar Not on different sites. And not really on the same site if you're not committing any vote fraud.

Comment: @Bart The inactivity would definitely qualify, but I think I had enough activity to not trigger the second clause. It just bugs me knowing I may have an account that I don't know about.

Comment: And you didn't use a name for that one? One that you could search for?

Comment: I do not see any accounts with a splitbits.com email address, sorry. Looks like your account was purged. It might be possible for a dev to resurrect it, though.

Comment: @mmyers I don't know if it's worth all that, I'll settle for knowing that I don't have a zombie account there. Thanks for looking it up.

Comment: @JulianHunter hey, don't give up, this place is fun!