# Are some meta accounts deleted?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I am pretty sure that I had an associated Meta account in Stack Exchange already and I have also asked a question. (Though it was marked duplicate and I am not able to search for that question anymore. Maybe it was deleted too?)

But today, when I came here, it asked me to sign-up again and re-associate with my account.

Was my account deleted for some reason in Meta? I don't see any reason if so, because all other Stack Exchange sites are perfectly fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The per-site meta accounts are not deleted separately from main accounts. The MSE account can be deleted by request of it's owner (unless it's a spammy account of course, then employes nuke it).

You've mistaken Meta Stack Overflow with Meta Stack Exchange, because there's the duplicate question you're talking about:

[Can SO add line numbers for any code posted in question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296734/can-so-add-line-numbers-for-any-code-posted-in-question)

And it is on the Meta Stack Overflow, correctly assigned to your MSO profile.

Comment: You are right... I didn't know there were 2 meta sites... Thanks...:)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, but is it possible that was before the MSO/MSE split? (See [Operation 'Split, All The Metas!' Shall Commence On April 16, 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/228888/245360))

If so, it might be that accounts that only had activity on MSO and not on MSE were not recreated as MSE.

I can't find any users in the list matching your user name, so it seems you didn't have an account here yet. (maybe you are mistaking with another meta?)

Also read: [When will inactive accounts be deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/48262/245360)

It is well possible you are matching the criteria:

> The user has not visited the site in six months
>
> AND
>
> The user has only 1 reputation (i.e. has never received an upvote)

Comment: Thanks a lot... I actually only had an account in MSO... I didn't even know there were different meta sites for SO and SE...

Comment: Yes, this is 'Capitol Hill', not your town hall.

Comment: This wasn't before the split and isn't related to it in any case; the problem is just mistaking two accounts.

Comment: Okay. That seems to be true now @nicael.