# Why was my previous account deleted automatically and how to get it back?

Tags: support, deleted-accounts

My previous account was deleted automatically. And on log in, a new account is created. And on my previous account **user398935** is showing in place of a name.

What's wrong with my account?

How do I get my account back?

And I noticed one thing my new account shows comments, upvotes, downvotes and reputation of my old account.

Comment: This is not the case. I am registered user and my account deleted automatically.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I misunderstood the question at first. More relevantly then: accounts are never deleted automatically. Do you recall receiving an email message related to your previous account?

Comment: Use the [Contact Us](http://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) form and explain the situation.

Comment: Can I know the reason of downvoting?

Comment: Maybe because most of us cannot help and only SE can look into deeper account issues.

Comment: @Seven: Actually, user profiles _are_ deleted automatically. They need to have had very little activity and been idle for quite some time, however. ([source](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48262/when-will-inactive-accounts-be-deleted))

Comment: On what site? Not really giving us enough information here. Links to the old profile/new profile pages?

Comment: @ale Thanks, that's a corner case I wasn't aware of!

Comment: Re the edit: this account you're posting with *doesn't* show any comments, upvotes, downvotes, or reputation on any site. Do you perhaps have more than one account?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not relevant anymore, since the account on that site and here have been deleted.

Answer (score 22):

The previous account on math.se was deleted by a moderator - the reason given was that it was a sock puppet for a different account.

That other account has been suspended for voting irregularities.